# powershell vs cmd regarding not closing the cmd/powershell window after execution

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, windows-10, intel-fortran

I have a `ipsxe-comp-vars.bat` batch file which sets environment variables for the intel fortran compiler, as well as for the c and c++ compilers. I create a shortcut to it, I right-click the shortcut, go to target and put the path of `cmd.exe` and a `/K` (such that the command prompt won't close) and a space before the path to the `.bat` in it, click on apply and ok. Then I can pin the shortcut to the taskbar. When I click on it : the bat is executed and at the end, I am back to the command prompt, the cmd window don't close. I can then start compiling etc in this command windows.

At the same place as the `.bat` file I created a `ipsxe-comp-vars.ps1` file :

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser Unrestricted
Set-Location "C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.210\windows\bin"
& "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /E:ON /V:ON "C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.210\windows\bin\ipsxe-comp-vars.bat" intel64 vs2015
```

Then I create a shortcut for this `.ps1` file, right-click the shortcut, and modify it's target as follows :

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit - command "& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.210\windows\bin\ipsxe-comp-vars.ps1'"
```

Then I can also pin this new shortcut to the taskbar. When I click on it : the `.ps1` file is executed, but the window closes, annihilating the leverage of the very notion of shorcut in this case.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure that `.ps1` is executed? You have extra space here `- command`, which should cause PowerShell to error out.

Comment: Yes. Typo here but not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following which is how my shortcuts with `-noexit` are set up.

`%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.210\windows\bin\ipsxe-comp-vars.ps1"`

**-Command**

Executes the specified commands (and any parameters) as though they were typed at the PowerShell command prompt, and then exits, unless the NoExit parameter is specified. Essentially, any text after -Command is sent as a single command line to PowerShell (this is different from how -File handles parameters sent to a script).

**-File []**

Runs the specified script in the local scope ("dot-sourced"), so that the functions and variables that the script creates are available in the current session. Enter the script file path and any parameters. File must be the last parameter in the command, because all characters typed after the File parameter name are interpreted as the script file path followed by the script parameters and their values.

You can include the parameters of a script, and parameter values, in the value of the File parameter. For example: `-File .\Get-Script.ps1 -Domain Central` Note that parameters passed to the script are passed as literal strings (after interpretation by the current shell). For example, if you are in cmd.exe and want to pass an environment variable value, you would use the cmd.exe syntax: `powershell -File .\test.ps1 -Sample %windir%` If you were to use PowerShell syntax, then in this example your script would receive the literal "$env:windir" and not the value of that environmental variable: `powershell -File .\test.ps1 -Sample $env:windir`

Typically, the switch parameters of a script are either included or omitted. For example, the following command uses the All parameter of the Get-Script.ps1 script file: `-File .\Get-Script.ps1 -All`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help?view=powershell-6

Comment: With your solution, lauching the shortcut ends up with a cmd window in the same state than the one one gets after having run the `.bat` shortcut (the first one I described in my question), in which all environment variables are rightly set. Doing an `exit` in this window leads to a PS command prompt, in which the environment variables are not set anymore ... (Which is what I intend to achieve in the first place.)